# How to make change on picker value with Picker when the picker items are mapped?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker

I don't success to change the  value selected of the picker.
When I click on other value it change correctly and after 0.2 sec it put the first value again.
I don't know why ...

Could you help me please ?

```js
 const [espaceSelected, setEspaceSelected] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getEspaces().then(data => {
            setEspaces(data);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('id_espace',espaces[0].id_espace);
            setEspaceSelected(espaces[2].name);
        })
    }, []);

...
return ( ...
  <Picker selectedValue={espaceSelected ? espaceSelected : null} onValueChange={(value) => { setEspaceSelected(value.name);}}>
                {espaces ? espaces.map(e => {
                    return (
                        <Picker.Item color="#7B65AE" label={e.name} value={e.id_espace} />);
                }) : null}
            </Picker>
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the render code for the `Picker` you set the value to `value={e.id_espace}` and then try to access the `value.name` in the `onValueChange`, but the `value` is only the `id` and not the object having an `id` and the `name`.

For example you can fix it, by using the `name` everywhere and not mixing it with the id or the object:

```
...onValueChange={(name) => { setEspaceSelected(name); }} ...
...
<Picker.Item color="#7B65AE" label={e.name} value={e.name} />
```